# CMake error: Could not find the VTK package with the following required components:GUISupportQt, ViewsQt

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I compiled VTK in my RedHat 8.3 machine, and now when I want to compile an example in the /GUI/Qt/SimpleView with cmake I get the following error message when configuring:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
Found package configuration file:
home/user/Downloads/VTK-9.1.0/build/lib64/cmake/vtk-9.1/vtk-config.cmake
but it set VTK_FOUND to FALSE so package “VTK” is considered to be NOT FOUND.
Reason given by package:
Could not find the VTK package with the following required components:
GUISupportQt, ViewsQt.
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: removed the word "compilation" from your title, because this is not a compile-time thing, but a configure-time thing.

Comment: well, have you install the VTK devel package?

Comment: During CMake configuration of VTK, did you set the "VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GuiSupportQt" and "VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_ViewsQt" options to "YES"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I just compile VTK from the source. I don't know if the devel package has been installed. What can I do to know if the package has been installed.

Comment: you don't need the devel package if you have compiled it yourself. your own build is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you did not set the  `VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GuiSupportQt` and `VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_ViewsQt` options to "YES" when running configure in CMake.

**Note:** the abovementioned option names are only applicable for VTK >= 9; for VTK < 9, they are called `Module_vtkGUISupportQt` and `Module_vtkViewsQt` (and you might also need to enable `Module_vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL` and `Module_vtkRenderingQt`).

These options are not enabled by default, but they seem to be required by the example that you're trying to compile.

Don't worry, you shouldn't have to re-do everything now. To fix:

- Open the CMake GUI.
- Enter the folder where you built VTK in "Where to build the binaries".
- If it's not checked, set the "Advanced" checkbox (the required options are not visible otherwise).
- Set `VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GuiSupportQt` and `VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_ViewsQt` options to "YES"
- Press "Configure", and wait for it to finish
- During Configuring, you might get an error, if CMake doesn't know how to find Qt; if so, enter the Qt5_DIR / Qt6_DIR, and press configure again.
- Press "Generate", and wait for it to finish
- Start the vtk build again (depends on what build tool you choose...)
- Try configuring the example again, now you should not see the error message anymore.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solves my problem.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue too I dont know how should I `Set VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_GuiSupportQt and VTK_MODULE_ENABLE_VTK_ViewsQt options to "YES"` ? I didnt underestand what should I do.

Comment: I should click on `Add Entry` if yes I do that but it didnt build

Comment: No it should already be in the (name, value) list of options below the "search" input field. **make sure you have the "advanced" checkbox checked**, as stated above, otherwise the option won't be visible. you can also use the search input field - just type Qt into the field, and the visible options will get filtered down to all options affecting vtk's Qt support

Comment: also make sure you are actually building VTK 9. For VTK < 9, the options have a different name